# trying to do dataflow job through terraform but got error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Er3tk.jpg)

> │ Error: googleapi: Error 404: (d958f8ba4ff671db): Unable to open template file: gs://sample_bucket_terraform/data_file., notFound
> │
> │   with google_dataflow_flex_template_job.big_data_job,
> │   on main.tf line 13, in resource "google_dataflow_flex_template_job" "big_data_job":

Comment: Please add any relevant terraform code to the question.

Comment: Please share your code snippet with Terraform ?

Comment: Hi i add code screen shot please check what mistake i have done

Comment: Code should be added as text, not as images

Answer (score 0):

In order to deploy flex template dataflow job, you have to [build a flex template image](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/using-flex-templates#create_a_flex_template) or use an existing flex template, then refer the flex template metadata json file in your terraform

> *container_spec_gcs_path=gs://sample_bucket_terraform/data_file.json*

refer this [link](https://medium.com/@emailchhavisharma/quick-steps-to-build-deploy-dataflow-flex-templates-python-java-728fc366f0d1) for step by step process to create flex template

Note:
The data_file.json should be available in the *gs://sample_bucket_terraform/* location.

Comment: Hi Balasubramanian , I tried with above steps i got this type of error googleapi: Error 404: (cedb997fb085acbe): Unable to open template file: gs://sample_bucket_terra/data_file.json., notFound